# Move mouse from current location to the JComponent location

Tags: java, swing, awtrobot, gui-testing

I would like to move my mouse pointer from current location to the specified Jcomponent automatically for GUI testing (without numbers in the method)

```
click(JComponent comp){
        robot.mouseMove(200, 50);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your software, you can use [AssertJ Swing](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing.html).

If you simply want to determine the component location you need to use the method `getLocationOnScreen`

```
click(JComponent comp){
    try {
        Point loc = comp.getLocationOnScreen();
        Dimension size = comp.getSize();
        // robot.mouseMove(loc.x, loc.y);
        // move to the center of component
        robot.mouseMove(loc.x + size.width / 2, loc.y + size.height / 2);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if component is not on the screen, an exception be thrown.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the complete example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * <code>RobotTest</code>.
 */
public class RobotTest {

    private Robot robot;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RobotTest()::startUp);
    }

    private void startUp() {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Autoclick");
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Click here");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Auto click");
        btn1.addActionListener(e -> click(btn2));
        btn2.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frm, "Autoclick done!"));
        frm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frm.add(btn1);
        frm.add(btn2);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void click(JComponent comp) {
        try {
            Point loc = comp.getLocationOnScreen();
            Dimension size = comp.getSize();
            // robot.mouseMove(loc.x, loc.y);
            // move to the center of component
            robot.mouseMove(loc.x + size.width / 2, loc.y + size.height / 2);
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if component is not on the screen, an exception be thrown.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the message but  "robot.mouseMove(loc.x + size.width / 2, loc.y + size.height / 2)" is not dragging my mouse to the component. Not sure why.

Comment: @user10478566 I've added an example, to demonstrate that the click method works. Please build a small example that demonstrates your usecase and post it in your question, so I can also run it and understand what's wrong.